# hide a <li> on desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a nav bar that contains one list item that I would like to hide for anyone looking at the site on a desktop.

My issue is the css code I am trying to use to hide a specific `<li>` tags content is not working and I am not sure why

here is my code

```
<style>
     @media only screen and (min-width:500px;) {
         li.showonmobile { display:none; visibility: hidden; }
     }
</style>
```

and then the li tag I want to hide on desktop is

```
      <li class="level0 level-top showonmobile" style="position:relative;"> <a class="open_special_offers" style="cursor:pointer">SPECIAL OFFERS</a>  
            <div id="special_offers_dropdown">
                <h3>ONLINE EXCLUSIVE</h3>
                <div class="so_content">
                    <center>Buy one get one free</center>
                </div>
            </div>
       </li>
```

Comment: I don't get it, is it still showing? Or is it not showing on mobile?

Comment: you want to hide it in desktop or phones?

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes He wants to hide it for people viewing on desktop. It should be visible only on mobile.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it working the way I need with C Travel's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this: (without the `;`)

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:500px) {
     li.showonmobile { display:none; visibility: hidden; }
 }
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pfL0nwLL/)**